# 301 redirect for php site on windows

Tags: php, windows, redirect

i have the following scenario:
old site, hosted somewhere. all pages except homepage are in the form of:
mydomain.com/page123 or some other number of course..

new site ,written in php, hosted on different server, a windows plan (cannot change that..)
all pages including homepage are in the form of:
mydomain.com/?page=some_name or

the idea is not loose the old pages rank so i was re commended to use 301 redirect
goal: all old urls should redirect to mydomain.com/?page=homepage 
problem(?): can't use htaccess on new server (tried, it doesn't not work)

php has:

```
<?
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
Header( "Location: http://www.new-url.com" );
?>
```

but where would i place this code? the old files are not present on the new site.

am i missing something here?
any suggestions?
Thanks and have a nice day :-)

Comment: "can't use htaccess on new server (tried, it doesn't not work)" - what's wrong with .htaccess ? any particular error ?

Comment: iis can be configured to redirect urls as well (not via .htaccess), in that case however, the question belongs to [Server](http://serverfault.com/Fault). The header() code should  be placed in a catch-all page, for example in the 404 page, or in a page all requests are routed to.

Comment: Your new server is out of the picture for making this work.  You need to update your old server to redirect the user to your new site.  What is your new server setup with (e.g. Apache, PHP, etc)?

Comment: The php code snippet would have to be placed into the PHP files on the old server. There's no point in putting a "we've moved" sign onto the door of your NEW house... you have to put the sign on the door of the OLD house.

Comment: What server do you actually use? Apache? ISS?

Comment: If your old server is Apache based, one fairly simple mod_rewrite rule with a `[R]` flag could do this job...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your site structure.
If you use MVC approach with one entering point like index.php you can add this code in your 
route controller and check that you get old url try to move to new url with header.

If you use another approach you should add redirect conditions in your apache/nginx server for each old pages.